# METAFONT can not find d7seg.mf

Tags: fonts, windows, metafont

I write a simple file (T.tex):

```
% T.tex
\documentclass{paper}

\newfont{\dviiseg}{d7seg scaled 1200}

\begin{document}
    $\mbox{\dviiseg{c}}(c)$
\end{document}
```

then I put the d7seg.mf to the current directory.
but miktex-mf.exe says:

```
Running miktex-mf.exe...

This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (MiKTeX 2.9)
! I can't find file `d7seg'.
 ... \mag:=magstep(1.0);nonstopmode;input d7seg

Please type another input file name

! Emergency stop.

 ... \mag:=magstep(1.0);nonstopmode;input d7seg

Transcript written on mfput.log.
```

My os is win7, and T.tex can not obtain output.

BTW:
When I run it in my laptop(XP + MikTeX 2.7), T.tex can obtain output pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes look as if the current directory is not searched. Put your mf in a local texmf tree in fonts\source.

Comment: Maybe my MikTeX has problem. If I copy d7seg.pk to the current directory, this problem is solved. And today I change to TeXLive 2011, this problem is also solved. I donot know why.

Comment: Well obviously miktex doesn't search the current directory for mf.files. This could be  deliberate (e.g. for security) or simply a bug: Make a bug report then you will get an explanation. Apart this: It is *much* better to put mf files in the correct directory in a local tree. And using pk-files is not a good idea, the resolution could be wrong.

Comment: I mean, when I uses TeXLive2011 and the current directory only include d7seg.mf, my tex file can work well. And METAFONT will generate d7seg.pk720 automatically.

Comment: I know what you mean. It doesn't work like this in the current miktex. You must put the mf in a texmf tree.

Comment: Would you like testing T.tex in your miktex environment? Today I only can test in TeXLive2011. When I move d7seg.mf to texlive/texmf-local/fonts/source, it does not work.

Comment: @Xie: 然后执行 texhash 命令

Comment: Now I move d7seg.mf to texlive/texmf-local/fonts/source/local, and execute texhash, it works! Thanks!!

Comment: I *did* test it in miktex. It *doesn't* work. I made a bug report. https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3393750&group_id=10783&atid=110783

Comment: oh...it's a bug:-) When I ran it in miktex2.7, it works very well. The font d7seg can produce 7-segment font (like digital watch time font). Since these files will be sent to the press, and I put d7seg.mf in the current file.

Comment: This bug was [reported again](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/672), and has now been fixed as of MikTeX 20.12. The resulting tfm/pk files still get installed into surprising places (not the current directory as with TeX Live), but that's a separate issue I didn't end up pursuing/(re)reporting.